# Move child value to parent - php multidimentional array

Tags: php

I had a problem on how to move the child value into the parent. The first and second loop is OK. But on the third loop, notice that there are array [0] with person name is included into the third loop. I have this array structure:

```
Array
(
 [TSK LEMPOR] => Array
    (
        [SAMSUL HADI] => Array
            (
                [0] => SAMSUL HADI
                [1] => 156
                [2] => 204
            )

        [HELMI ALMASAKTI] => Array
            (
                [0] => HELMI ALMASAKTI
                [1] => 156
                [2] => 204
            )

    )

)
```

it suppose to be like this:

```
Array
(
 [TSK LEMPOR] => Array
    (
        [SAMSUL HADI] => Array
            (
                [0] => 156
                [1] => 204
            )

        [HELMI ALMASAKTI] => Array
            (
                [0] => 156
                [1] => 204
            )

    )

)
```

generated from this code:

```
$attendance = array();

    foreach($projects as $project) {

        $workers = DB::table('tk_worker')
                   ->where('w_id', $project->tkat_wid)
                   ->select('w_id','w_name')
                   ->get();

        foreach($workers as $worker) {

            $attendance[$project->plpr_description][$worker->w_name]['a'] = $worker->w_name;

            $activities = DB::table('tk_attendance')
                          ->where('tkat_projectid',$project->plpr_projectid)
                          ->where('tkat_wid',$worker->w_id)
                          ->groupby('tkat_activityid')->get();

            foreach($activities as $activity) {

                $attendance[$project->plpr_description][$worker->w_name][] = $activity->tkat_activityid;

            }

        }
    }
```

So please help me.

Comment: What does this line do : `$attendance[$project->plpr_description][$worker->w_name]['a'] = $worker->w_name;` ? Have you tried changing it to `$attendance[$project->plpr_description][$worker->w_name] = array();` ?

Comment: thank you roberto06, i just try your suggestion and it works.. thank you again...